# HTML/JSP | <select> setting selected index with value

Tags: html, jsp

I have a select tag in witch I want to go to the second option. I know I can do it with

`<option selected="selected" ></option>`

but with my dynamic website that is just too dificult to go throug all of these Options. I dont want to use any JavaScript if its not needed. I'm using JSP. Is there a way to use this to select a option? And if there is no way with JSP how can I use Javascript and JSP together?

```
<select name="months" value="<%=request.getParameter.('currentMonth')%>" id="monthSelect">
  <option value="1">Januar</option>
  <option value="2">Februar</option>
  <option value="3">März</option>
  <option value="4">April</option>
  <option value="5">Mai</option>
  <option value="6">Juni</option>
  <option value="7">Juli</option>
  <option value="8">August</option>
  <option value="9">September</option>
  <option value="10">Oktober</option>
  <option value="11"> November</option>
  <option value="12"> Dezember</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use for iteration to generate and select options:

```
<%
   String[] month = new String[]{"Januar", ...};
   int selected = 5; // e.g.
%>
<select>
<%
   for(int i = 0; i < month.length; i++) {
%>
   <option value="<%=i+1%>" 
     <%=selected == i ? "selected=\"selected\"" : ""%>>
     <%=month[i]%>
   </option>
<%
   }
%>
</select>
```

Hope this helps.